# Should I use onClick or addEventListener(click) for a if statement on my JavaScript Quiz?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, onclick, addeventlistener

I'm making a JavaScript Quiz for school and they want me to use if/else statements to check if a anwser is correct. I'm using arrays to get questions from JavaScript to the button in HTML. One var with a array which contains questions and four variables with arrays for each option(A,B,C,D). That's where the choices are.

```
var buttonA = document.getElementById("button1") //Here I made a reference to the buttons
var buttonB = document.getElementById("button2")
var questions = ["What is 1+1?"] //I made a array where it can be read of, real concept contains more questions ofc
var choices = ["2", "3"] //I made choices to choose, button1 will be linked to choice "2" and button2 to "3"
```

So if I want to check if a anwser is correct with a if statement. How would I define this in JavaScript? I know I can make one option correct by just making a function, but I really want to know if anwser checking can be done with a if statement if the questions and arrays are being read from arrays. Please note that English is not my mother langauge and I suffer from PDD/NOS so I am not good in describing my questions properly, so please let me know if you need additional info.

Comment: This is confusing. The title says you're asking about `onclick` versus `addEventListener`. But the question text seems to be about how to organize your data, not how to attach the event handler.

Comment: I recommend using an array of objects. Each object will contain a question, all the choices, and the correct answer.